# How to monitor k3s/rancher pods?

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

The problems I'm facing are these pods crash out of nowhere and I'm unable to debug why it happened. How can I monitor them?

Answer (score 0):

Keep a shell open with `watch kubectl get events` and observe the output when pods start/restart.